# Who is Sakamoto?

Tags: wagatsuma-san-wa-ore-no-yome

In Chapter 5 (I Won't Get Pool Again) of *Wagatsuma-san wa Ore no Yome*, the following scenes appear on page 11. In that scene, the person being called Sakamoto is actually called Itou.

[image: panel from page 11 of chapter 5]

I guess it might be some kind of parody. Which character or human was being parodied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a parody of [Ryoma Sakamoto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sakamoto_Ry%C5%8Dma) (坂本健太), a prominent figure and force behind the overthrowing of the Tokugawa Shogunate (during the Bakumatsu period) which led to the Meiji Restoration, and one of his quotations:

> 人間、好きな道によって世界を切り拓いてゆく
>
> People make their way in life by following their hearts

As a side note, the Underdog Scans translation is rife with inaccuracies GIA, which is Gesu (not "guess," which can mean anything from lowlife to humble person, the ambiguity here seems intentional) Intelligence Agency. his is the same kind of "gesu" as the "Gesu-ling Club" from *Sket Dance*.

Comment: Dang, here I was hoping it could be referring to [*the* Sakamoto](http://i.imgur.com/iJfkYdj.jpg)... :P